# How to ignore all directories in a folder that don't begin with @?

Tags: git, gitignore

In my project, I have a *src/apps/* directory.  I want `git` to ignore all subdirectories that don't begin with an *@* symbol (keep *src/apps/@dir/* or *src/apps/file*).

```
package.json
    |
.gitignore
    |
   src/ - - -
            |
          apps/ - - -
                    |
              keep-this-file
                    |
              keep-this-file-too
                    |
              @keep-this-dir/
                    |
              @keep-this-dir-too/
                    |
              ignore-this-dir/
                    |
              ignore-this-dir-too/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.gitignore` file can also define exclusions for ignored files:

```
src/apps/*/
!src/apps/@*/
```

This ignores all files in the `src/apps` directory except everything in that directory that starts with `@`.

Comment: Can it be more specific?  The only things I'm trying to exclude are directories that don't begin with _@_.  Files found in the _apps/_ directory should be saved.

Comment: Would the pattern for only excluding directories that begin with _@_ look like this `!src/apps/@*/` ?

Comment: Path patterns in the `.gitignore` are ignored. If they begin with a `!`, the files will **not** be ignored.

Comment: And, as I stated in my answer: *This ignores the src/apps directory except everything in that directory that starts with `@`.*

Comment: Yes, but I don't think you need the `/` at the end

Comment: Right.  _except everything in that directory that starts with @_.  This means the files in that directory would be ignored if they don't begin with _@_, (like _src/apps/scripts.js_) correct?

Comment: Yes, they would be ignored.

Comment: But you will need to add both lines.

Comment: That's the issue.  I don't want any files to be ignored, just directories.  My apologies if I wasn't clear.